# Xdebug is not recognizing the breakpoint

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, xdebug

- PHP version 7.1
- Ubuntu 18.04
- Laravel 7.0
- Application path: `/Desktop/P10Software/laravel7`

Path mapping is correct or not not able to fix it

```
    {
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/Desktop/P10Software/laravel7/": "${workspaceFolder}/"
            },
            "xdebugSettings": {
                "max_data": 65535,
                "show_hidden": 1,
                "max_children": 100,
                "max_depth": 5
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: 1) You are on Linux .. so try different port for Xdebug (in VSCode settings and php.ini) -- try 9001. There is a chance that default TCP 9000 port is already used by **php-fpm**. You may check that using `netstat` or similar program (what process is listening on that port). Other than that: 2) what are your Xdebug settings? 3) Collect and share Xdebug log for such unsuccessful debug session.

Comment: i have tried after changing but still i am facing same issue  any other way to resolve it the issue